# Do actions in each folder from current directory via terminal

Tags: bash

I'm trying to run a series of commands on a list of files in multiple directories located directly under the current branch.

An example hierarchy is as follows:

```
/tmp
  |-1
  | |-a.txt
  | |-b.txt
  | |-c.txt
  |-2
  | |-a.txt
  | |-b.txt
  | |-c.txt
```

From the `/tmp` directory I'm sitting at my prompt and I'm trying to run a command against the `a.txt` file by renaming it to `d.txt`.

How do I get it to go into each directory and rename the file? I've tried the following and it won't work:

```
for i in ./*; do
  mv "$i" $"(echo $i | sed -e 's/a.txt/d.txt/')"
done
```

It just doesn't jump into each directory. I've also tried to get it to create files for me, or folders under each hierarchy from the current directory just 1 folder deep, but it won't work using this:

```
for x in ./; do
  mkdir -p cats
done
```

**OR**

```
for x in ./; do
  touch $x/cats.txt
done
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: `for i in ./*/*` perhaps? Or use `find` to loop recursively through all files, dirs, subdirs etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the below script in your base directory

```
#!/bin/bash
# Move  'a.txt's to 'd.txt's recursively
mover()
{
CUR_DIR=$(dirname "$1")
mv "$1" "$CUR_DIR/d.txt"
}
export -f mover
find . -type f -name "a.txt" -exec bash -c 'mover "$0"' {} \;
```

and execute it.

**Note:**

If you wish be a bit more innovative and generalize the script, you could accept directory name to search for as a parameter to the script and pass the directory name to `find`

Comment: I like this script because I can do a lot more with this and didn't even think to use the `find` tool in this scenario. It's perfect. Thank you.

Comment: @Danijel-JamesW : You're welcome pal. `find` is handy especially when you're dealing with non-standard filenames. NBD here I guess..

Answer (score 1):

```
> for i in ./*; do
```

As per your own description, this will assign `./1` and then `./2` to `i`.  Neither of those matches any of the actual files.  You want

```
for i in ./*/*; do
```

As a further aside, the shell is perfectly capable of replacing simple strings using glob patterns.  This also coincidentally fixes the problem with not quoting `$i` when you `echo` it.

```
  mv "$i" "${i%/a.txt}/d.txt"
```